# How to reverse the order of two branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I created 2 branches `dev`, and `local`. After I created them I tried to see the topology (which seems to be reversed in my case) using `git show-branch --all`:

```
* [dev] Add Phong Blinn Model Shader
 ! [local] Add Phong Blinn Model Shader
  ! [master] Add Phong Blinn Model Shader
   ! [origin/HEAD] Add Phong Blinn Model Shader
    ! [origin/master] Add Phong Blinn Model Shader
```

How can I reverse the order of the branches `dev`, and `local`?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse the order"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean that I swap the local branch to be in the lowest level of the topology instead of dev branch.

Comment: What "topology"? Did you read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch` will only list branch names, regardless of their dependencies to one another.

Try `git log` :

```
git log --all --oneline --graph ---simplify-by-decoration
```

If you want to view the dependencies of one individual branch, replace the `--all` option with that branch name :

```
git log --oneline --graph ---simplify-by-decoration local
```

Comment: how can I **visualize** the **dependencies** then?